# Is every complete Boolean algebra a complete subalgebra of some powerset algebra?

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra

Is every complete Boolean algebra $B$ a complete subalgebra of some powerset algebra $P(X)$, in the sense that the inclusion map preserves infinite meets and joins?

Comment: Wouldn't a complete subalgebra of a power set algebra necessarily be atomic? So wouldn't any nonatomic complete Boolean algebra be a counterexample?

Comment: Of course a complete **atomic** Boolean algebra is isomorphic to a power set algebra.

Comment: For $x\in B$ let $x^*=\{y\in B: xy=y\}.$ Let $x_1^*\times^* x_2^*=(x_1x_2)^*=x_1^*\cap x_2^*$ and let $x_1^*+^*x_2^*=(x_1+x_2)^*=\{y_1+y_2: y_1\in x_1^*\land y_2\in x_2^*\}.$